# Meaning, origin, and usage of “cor lummy”

Tags: meaning, etymology

I came across an expression I’ve never seen before when reading a [Kate Atkinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Atkinson) novel. A quick internet search netted little information apart from a possible cockney origin as a  distorted form of “god, love me”.  Does anyone have any more information on meaning, origin, and usage?

**Update**

Here is the excerpt from the novel:

> ‘You’ve been in a fight!’ Amelia looked at him for the first time but when he caught her eye she looked away. ‘How exciting,’ Julia said.
>   ‘It was nothing,’ Jackson said. (Just someone’s trying to kill me.)
>   ‘What day is it today?’ ‘Tuesday,’ Julia said promptly. Amelia grunted
>   something that sounded like ‘Wednesday.’ ‘Really?’ Julia said to her.
>   ‘Cor lummy, how the days fly, don’t they?’ (Cor lummy? Who said things
>   like that? Apart from Julia?) ‘I always think,’ Julia said, ‘that
>   Wednesdays are violet.’ Julia seemed in an exceptionally merry mood.
>   ‘And Tuesdays are yellow, of course.’

Comment: Please provide context.

Comment: How does one get from "God" to "cor"?

Comment: BrE is mostly non-rhotic, so  ‹cor› is pronounced without the r as if it were *caw*. Gawd  → caw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is indeed a euphemistic or 'minced oath' version of "God love me" - with the verb, here, in the optative mood ("may God love me" or "as I hope God loves me") to invoke the Deity as guarantor of the speaker's sincerity. An analogue is  "corblimey" < "God blame me", that is,  May God impute sin to me (if I'm not speaking the truth).

- ADDED, 3/14/17: An anonymous reviewer suggests that *blimey* derives from *blind me*. That seems equally likely, and appears to be the sense in which the word was understood by late 19th-century observers.

It's 'cockney' in the broad sense of 'colloquial lower-class British', but it's not restricted to the area within earshot of Bow Bells and it's not rhyming slang.

Answer (score 5):

[Partridge](http://books.google.fi/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=%22cor%20lummy%22%20OR%20%22cor%20lumme%22%20OR%20%22cor%20lumy%22&source=bl&ots=cROvTWKUgv&sig=iP8Ssyf-kn5tRvzIQptGctTRScY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7Yc3UKioH-eK4gT5ooCYDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22cor%20lummy%22%20OR%20%22cor%20lumme%22%20OR%20%22cor%20lumy%22&f=false) (2008) says:

> **cor lummie!; cor lumme!; cor lummy!** used as a general-purpose expletive. A cockney variation of 'God love me!'; almost stereotypically Cockney but later use tends towards irony. *UK, 1961*

Although it's probably from around the late-1920s to mid-1930s; *Cor lumme!* appears in a number of magazine snippets in Google Books.

---

According to the OED, *Cor* is a vulgar corruption of *God* and first documented in J.B. Priestley's *Angel Pavement* (1931):

> Cor! — you're in the wrong part of the theatre, boy.

*Lummy* is also a corruption of *(Lord) love me*, first quoted in J.D. Brayshaw's *Slum Silhouettes* (1898)

> Wot! Pay for me death? Oh, lummy! not me.

The OED also quotes D.L. Sayers' *Gaudy Night* (1935):

> ‘Lor' lumme!’ I says, ‘there's old Winderpane gawn.’

*Lummy* is also slang for first-rate, and first documented in Dickens' *Oliver Twist* (1838):

> Jack Dawkins — lummy Jack — the Dodger — the Artful Dodger.

Comment: Agreed that it's used in novels written in the 1920's such as Dorothy Sayers' wonderful following of Lord Peter Wimsey.
In 'Murder Must Advertise', a young Cockney lad says, during a police interview..."Wot I meantersay, the time 'as come fer me ter divulge wot I know, and I ain't agoin' - cor lumme!"